# Pandas concat fail and appear NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, nan

I want vertical concat two dataframe but I have no idea why it concact by ['data_label'] and generate NaN?

```
print(leakage_data1)

    0    1    2   data_label
0  0.2  0.1  0.7      0
1  0.5  0.6  0.4      0


print(noise_data1)

    0    1    2   data_label
0  0.9  0.8  1.0      1
1  0.7  0.5  0.1      1
```

I use `model1_TestData = pd.concat([leakage_data1, noise_data1], axis=0, ignore_index=True)`
and got

```
print(model1_TestData)

    0    1    2   data_label   0    1    2
0  0.2  0.1  0.7      0       NaN  NaN  NaN
1  0.5  0.6  0.4      0       NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN      1       0.9  0.8  1.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN      1       0.7  0.5  0.1
```

How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Check the data types on your column names. If one df has a string column name '1' and another is 1, it will print out on the screen the same but will give you the error you see there because to concat you have to have exactly the same column names and 1!='1'

```
model1_TestData.columns
```

should reveal something like `Index(['0', '1',..., 0, 1], dtype='object')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to just use

```
df.merge(df1, right_index = True, left_index = True)
```

when you are using axis =0 you are essentially telling it to do it via rows instead of columns...unless you are trying to do that, so you would want your data to simply be more vertical instead of horizontal?

Comment: Sorry I forgot write, I  want verical concat  two datas.

Comment: Updated my answer, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I find the problem that two dataframe column's name type not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({0:[.2, .5], 1:[.1, .6], 2:[.7, .4], 'data_label':0})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0:[.9, .7], 1:[.8, .5], 2:[1., .1], 'data_label':1})
print(pd.concat([df1, df2]))
```

Result:

```
     0    1    2  data_label
0  0.2  0.1  0.7           0
1  0.5  0.6  0.4           0
0  0.9  0.8  1.0           1
1  0.7  0.5  0.1           1
```